# Spring expression in xml configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

It is useful to have different property sets for different users.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:/path/to/package/default.properties,
        classpath:/path/to/package/#{ systemProperties['user.name'] }.properties"/>

</beans>
```

When executing the application, spring does not recognize the expression. The context does not start and spring says: `class path resource [path/to/package/#{ systemProperties['user.name'] }.properties] cannot be opened`

When I replace the expression manually with a string resulting in a valid resource then the behaviour is as expected. The [manual states](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html#expressions-beandef) it should work.

The spring-context and spring-core (3.1.2-RELEASE) are in classpath.

- How come spring does not pick up the environment variable?
- I'm open to alternate solutions solving the same functional problem.

Comment: what happens? Does the context start? Is the EL not translated at all, or are you seeing an unexpected value?

Comment: Thanks jalynn2. I edited the question to include the behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SpEL expressions are not allowed there; you can do what you want indirectly, though...

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="props"/>

<util:properties id="props" location="classpath:#{systemProperties['foo']}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Gary! Your suggestion lead to the solution. Adding properties and a local-override to the placeholder also keeps the default -> useroverride functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete answer to the question. Keeping the override of user properties over default properties. My edit of the accepted answer got rejected.

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="springContextCongifurationProperties"
                              location="classpath:/path/to/package/default.properties"
                              local-override="true"/>

<util:properties id="springContextCongifurationProperties"
                 location="classpath:/path/to/package/#{ systemProperties['user.name'] }.properties"/>
```